# Warning: FindNodeDom is deprecated in Strictmode when using Collapse (from react-bootstrap)

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am having an issue with this code in my React project. It would show a div with a warning about filenames to upload.

```
<Collapse in={this.state.open} id={"z-hover"}>
   <div>
     <ul>
       { FilesAllowed.files.map((fileName, index) => {
         return <li key={index}>{fileName}</li>
       })}
     </ul>
   </div>
</Collapse>
```

I use a button to display the Collapse element (from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/#collapse)), but when the Collapse gets displayed, console returns this error (I can confirm it comes exactly from the Collapse element):

```
 findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node
```

Edit: I put my functional code over here in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-hoover-rl1lx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

how could we do to avoid this warning? Thank you for reading:)

Comment: Hard to know without a minimal working example. Anyway looks like a package issue: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5075 + Also try to update the `react-bootstrap` package  (On version 1.4.3 sandbox I do not get this warning). Playground her: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/code-sandbox-examples/blob/master/README.md